# Weak Representability and Derivability Condition 1

Tags: logic, proof-theory, meta-math, provability

Can someone point out the error in the following reasoning?

Let K be an axiomatizable, consistent extension of Peano Arithmetic. Let *P'* denote the Gödel number for *P*.

1. K is axiomatizable, thus Thm(k) is recursively enumerable, thus **Thm(K) is weakly representable**. This means
   $$P ∈ Thm(K) ⇔ K ⊢ Prov(P')$$
2. **Derivability Condition 1** is
   $$K ⊢ P ⇒ K ⊢ Prov(P')$$
   The converse of this is **not** necessarily true.
3. By definition
   $$P ∈ Thm(K) ⇔ K ⊢ P$$

If all three are true, we get a contradiction because (1) and (3) imply the converse of (2), which does not necessarily hold. Can someone explain what is wrong here and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming statement 3, statement 2 is just the $\Rightarrow$ version of statement 1, and the converse of statement 2 is just the $\Leftarrow$ version of statement 1. So the issue is that the $\Leftarrow$ version of statement 1 also does not always hold, for the same reason that the converse of statement 2 does not always hold.

This leaves the question of how, if Thm($K$) is weakly representable, there is no contradiction. The answer is that, although Thm($K$) is weakly representable in a wide class of theories, in general the formula used to weakly represent it is **not** the formula $\text{Prov}(n)$. That formula only represents the set Thm($K$) under the assumption that every $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence provable in $K$ is true, an assumption known as $\Sigma^0_1$-soundness that is not true in general. So, although Thm($K$) is weakly representable, this does not mean that
$$
P \in \text{Thm}(K) \Leftrightarrow K \vdash \text{Prov}(P').
$$

Nevertheless, the following theorem does hold:

> **Representability Theorem.**  For every consistent recursively axiomatizable theory $K$ in the language of arithmetic, if $K$ includes Robinson Arithmetic $Q$ then every semi-recursive relation is weakly representable in $K$.

In the case where the theory is $\Sigma^0_1$ sound, the proof is essentially just Gödel numbering: we take an algorithm that semi-decides the relation, and we encode the algorithm into a formula of arithmetic.

The proof is more complicated, however, in the general case. One exposition of the full proof is on pp. 382-384 of Hinman, *Fundamentals of Mathematical Logic*, 2005.  The proof method uses Rosser's trick and the diagonalization lemma.

The fact that the formula representing Thm($K$) is not, in general, the formula $\text{Prov}(n)$ is not emphasized in many sources, such as in the Stanford Encyclopedia article on the incompleteness theorems, so it is easy to be confused by this point.  Moreover, some sources implicitly assume that they are only dealing with $\Sigma^0_1$-sound or with $\omega$-consistent theories, and sometimes it is hard to tell exactly what assumptions about the theory are being made.

Comment: Specifically, the right-to-left direction of (1) is false because $K$ may think that $K$ proves $P$ in a nonstandard number of steps, or by use of nonstandard axioms of $K$ itself. E.g. if we take $K=PA+\neg Con(PA)$, then $K$ proves "$K$ proves $0=1$" but (presumably :P) $K$ does not, in fact, prove $0=1$.

Comment: Is then both section 2.2 of [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#Rep) and pg 40 of [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ahBLqshTFMwC&pg=PA514&lpg=PA514&dq=%22weakly+representable%22+set&source=bl&ots=AZtvPIQXwx&sig=T2iC_uuJjLboibvLAWNonyFdQrU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil8JPkhMzMAhVBLSYKHUMkAEwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22weakly%20representable%22%20set&f=false) incorrect, or is there some difference I am not seeing?

Comment: @Just Some Old Man  I see now what you were asking. I expanded the answer some, I hope it helps. Please feel free to follow up here if there is some part of the answer that should be expanded further.

Comment: Thank you. That *Prov()* does't necessarily weakly represent *Thm(K)* seems pretty important, yet many sources don't seem to mention it. If *Thm(K)* is weakly representable, but not by *Prov()*, then what relation weakly represents it? Why does *Prov()* suddenly fail at it's job and who is his replacement? Also, is $\Sigma^0_1$-soundness of K the weakest condition that entails the converse of (1)? Can we conclude K is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound iff $$P ∈ Thm(K) \Leftarrow K ⊢ Prov(P')$$